# Group by based on priority in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write a stored procedure or SQL statements which needs to be run for around 1M records for an Oracle database. This should fetch the data based on priority as defined.

[image]

1 is highest priority and 4 is lowest.

When the records are group by using Cust ID, it should select only that record which is of highest priority as per source name else move to next source for priority within that group.

[image]

I am using old school ways by using LISTAGG and then check for value of Source name = A and then fetch all the data.

Is there any better way to extract the information.

The output should only contain records as per priority for each Group BY of Cust ID
[image]

Comment: *"select only that record which is of highest priority"*. So, is `1` highest priority or `4`? Looking at your output I'd guess `1` but I really shouldn't have to guess, you should be explaining your rules to me.

Comment: Anyway, this site already has plenty of similar questions: please scan some of these threads on [`[oracle]`+`[greatest-n-per-group]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle%2bgreatest-n-per-group?tab=Votes) for some idea of how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.CUSTID ORDER BY P.PRIORITY) AS RN 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T JOIN PRIORITY_TABLE P
ON T.SOURCE_NAME = P.SOURCE_NAME)
WHERE RN = 1
```